# Backup a Veracrypt encrypted external harddrive with time machine

Tags: macos, backup, time-machine, external-disk, encryption

I already searched a substantial amount of time but did not succeed yet.

I used VeraCrypt to fully encrypt my external hard drive named `Media` which contains a lot of media files such as photos, videos and music. Now, I want to backup the external harddrive to another external harddrive called `Backups` using Time Machine. Before I encrypted `Media` with VeraCrypt it I was just using Time Machine to create backups on `Backups`. Unfortunately, it does not work anymore. So, my questions are:

1. Is VeraCrypt compatible with Time Machine, i.e. can I use Time Machine to backup a Veracrypt encrypted external harddrive?
2. Can I encrypt the external harddrive `Backups` with VeraCrypt instead of the built in macOS encryption software and still use Time Machine?

**EDIT:** I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.7

Comment: It does make me wonder why you're not using FileVault. If the drive is not HFS or APFS Time Machine won't back it up anyway.

Comment: Simple reasoning: 1) VeraCrypt is available for macOS, Windows and Linux. 2) VeraCrypt is free & open source and is audited publicly, so there exist no unknown hidden doors. Are `Mac OS Extended (journaled)` volumes not supported?

Comment: All flavours of HFS+ [in fact probably plain old HFS isn't any more, I was just using it as shorthand]. TM's format has changed since Big Sur, which may explain why it down't work any more. Big Sur & up require the TM volume to be APFS, prior OSes demanded HFS+

Comment: Thank you for this information - I included in the post the macOS version I use. However, as far as I can remember the `Media` volume was formatted as `Mac OS Extendet (journaled)` before as well and it worked with TM...

Comment: After a brief look at veracrypt, it seems like it mounts a fuse filesystem when you decrypt. Therefore, you need to select the fuse filesystem as a location to copy in Time Machine.

Comment: However, FUSE probably don't support fsevents, so each Time Machine operation would have to scan the whole volume again. Therefore, it would be much more efficient for you to use FileVault if possible.

Comment: Can you be more explicit of what I would have to do "to select the fuse filesystem as a location to copy in Time Machine"? I unmounted `Media` using VeraCrypt. When I open TM and click on "options" I see the `Media` volume under the volumes which are excluded from backing up. Of course, I tried to remove it but it is grey and not clickable. So, I do not know what to do. Additional information to the second comment of @JoyJin I read: https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7553425 which says that it should work I guess?

Comment: Please report here if you get better answers from https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/technical/thread/ceec430eb1/

Comment: IMHO you are making a big mistake trying to use VeraCrypt for disk encryption on macOS. Use VeraCrypt for some few files requiring special protection - and that is all. FileVault is the way to go on macOS, if only because it is so deeply embedded in the OS. Even if you get something working, you will be running risk of it not working after any macOS update. If you really need open source (for supposed security benefits), you should not be using macOS - a Linux distribution will suit you better.

Comment: I will investigate this issue further. Of course, if I get appropriate answers I will post them here.